# How can I change application information shown in "Windows is ready" notifications?

Tags: gnome-shell

Does anyone know how can I change the text content and icons shown in the "Windows is ready" notifications? As I understand, these notifications appear when a program that is out of focus is loaded and ready to use (see pic). Please do share insights if these are named differently and whether you know of relevant documentation.

[image: "Windows is ready" picture]

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to change what an application reports? Or do you want to send notifications with your own text and icons? If it's latter here's an example of how to send a notification using `notify-send`:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Send a notification with the `help-faq` icon:

   ```
   notify-send "Hello World!" "This is an example of a message." -i help-faq
   ```

   ***Note:** To see a full list of default icons, [check out the standard icon names](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/latest/ar01s04.html) list.*

This will give you a notification like this:

[image: Notification Message]

And it will also appear in the notifications list:

[image: Notifications List]

Comment: thanks for the response! I would like to change what my application reports. Basically, Ubuntu is showing notifications with the wrong icon for my app.. I've proceeded to change the icon in my program's resources but the notifications are still showing the wrong icon which is the problem I'm trying to fix. Presumably Ubuntu is accessing the old icon from somewhere in the machine, but I'm not really sure where.. I was hoping someone would know if there was any documentation about these notifications and how to change them.

Comment: I would never have guessed that you had modified the icons of the source application based on the words contained in the question. Either way, that’s something I have zero experience doing, so can’t be of much help 